# How to use the VSCode debugger when testing a Solana Anchor program

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

Is there a way to use the VSCode debugger on a [Solana Anchor program](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/milestone_project_tic-tac-toe.html). For instance how could I add a breakpoint and stop execution on [line 6 of the Tic-Tac-Toe program](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor-book/blob/0466b036aa11e881ff62562c9290a1720e685f63/programs/tic-tac-toe/programs/tic-tac-toe/src/instructions/play.rs#L6) whenever I run the JS tests.

I have followed these steps:

- Installed [LLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) and [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer) extensions in VSCode.
- Created a **launch.json** file with following content:

  ```
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "lldb",
               "request": "launch",
               "name": "Debug unit tests in library 'tic-tac-toe'",
               "cargo": {
                   "args": [
                       "test",
                       "--package=tic-tac-toe"
                   ],
                   "filter": {
                       "name": "tic-tac-toe",
                       "kind": "lib"
                   }
               },
               "args": [],
               "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
           }
       ]
   }
  ```

But this seems to execute `cargo test` instead of `anchor test`. How can I configure the debugger to work with `anchor test`?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of. I do most of my debugging with the `msg!` macro and then inspect the program logs.
See also this helpful Gist: https://gist.github.com/briangershon/89dfe197941c0abbd26db991ce350ce5